# Shadow dom usage in polymer 3 app (youtube.com example)

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

**UPDATE**: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5551 - they use shadyDom

Youtube team recently updated their code to Polymer 3.x

If you go to youtube and open dev tools, you don't see any shadow dom at all:

[image]

However, when you start a new Polymer 3 app, shadow dom is here, as it was in previous versions. 
[image]

There are a lot of discussions about how great it will be to be able to render certain components without shadow dom. Seems like youtube team has succeeded in this.

> Shadow dom is great for component development, but pages, for
>   instance, should not be treated as components, IMHO. Treating
>   everything as a component (with ShadowDom) turns out to a be pain -
>   issues with styling, third party libs and more.

My question is: How youtube team achieved this?

Comment: I don't think they are using only Polymer. In Google they have their own framework which uses Polymer and something other. So basically, if youtube team could achieve  something, it doesn't mean you will be able too. If you want to disable shadow dom for whole website, you can use `window.ShadyDOM = {force: true};`

Comment: `if youtube team could achieve something, it doesn't mean you will be able too` I will respectfully disagree.

Comment: you are right. You will always be able to do anything you want. But for what price. Google is using more frameworks than only Polymer. In this case, you propably asked how to disable shadow dom for the entire website? because in your image I dont see any shadow dom

Answer (score 1):

Posibly they are using this:

[polymer reference](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#stamp-templates-in-light-dom)

emphasis mine :

> Customize DOM initialization
>
> There are several points where you can
>   customize how Polymer initializes your element's DOM. You can
>   customize how the shadow root is created by creating it yourself. And
>   you can override the _attachDom method to change how the the DOM tree
>   is added to your element: for example, **to stamp into light DOM** instead
>   of shadow DOM.
>
> **Stamp templates in light DOM**
>
> You can customize how the DOM is stamped by overriding the _attachDom
>   method. The method takes a single argument, a DocumentFragment
>   containing the DOM to be stamped. If you want to stamp the template
>   into light DOM, simply add an override like this:
>
> _attachDom(dom) {   this.appendChild(dom); } When you stamp the DOM template to light DOM like this, data bindings and declarative event
>   listeners work as usual, but you cannot use shadow DOM features, like
>    and style encapsulation.
>
> A template stamped into light DOM shouldn't contain any  tags.
>   Styles can be applied by an enclosing host element, or at the document
>   level if the element isn't used inside another element's shadow DOM.

About the styling in litelement, now you can do:

```
static get styles() {
    return css`
        :host {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .boxing rect {
            x: -24;
            y: -14;
            width: 48px;
            height: 28px;
            rx: 8;
            ry: 8;
        }
        .copia rect.text {
            width: 135px;
            height: 30px;
            stroke:blue;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }

        text {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        ${miGestorEstilos.getDibujaGafa()}
        ${miGestorEstilos.getDibujaForma()}
    `
}
```

Notice that this function can be shared across modules, and is composable with other functions returning also "CSS"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it was pretty simple, they do use ShadyDom. More info I got in their official repo: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5551

Comment: As a side note, I found out that migrating to lit-element greatly reduces the issues with styling that you said. (I am currently using shadow-dom for pages...)

Comment: could you please provide more details on this? I went through documentation of `lit-element` and did not notice a lot of styling differences.

Comment: Added an example in the answer